# Python - Graphing normal distribution line with list of data

Tags: python-3.x, math, machine-learning

I'm working on the Electrical Engineering project which requires plotting the normal distribution of the list of data.

We randomly measured the resistance of 30 resistors and wrote down them.

> X = [14.95, 14.94, 14.92, 14.98, 16.53, 14.96, 16.20, 14.32, 15.32, 14.25, 15.36, 14.95, 15.13, 14.26, 14.94, 15.6,
>        15.20, 14.94, 15.02, 15, 14.62, 14.94, 14.94, 14.98, 15.12, 15.06, 14.95, 14.96, 15.13, 15.20]

I want to get graph like this:

[image]

But I get the graph like this one:

[image]

I have to get more values in the graph where datum is near to mean.

This is the code that I'm using currently:

```js
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

X = [14.95, 14.94, 14.92, 14.98, 16.53, 14.96, 16.20, 14.32, 15.32, 14.25, 15.36, 14.95, 15.13, 14.26, 14.94, 15.6,
     15.20, 14.94, 15.02, 15, 14.62, 14.94, 14.94, 14.98, 15.12, 15.06, 14.95, 14.96, 15.13, 15.20]

X = np.sort(X)
mean = np.mean(X)

sigma = 0

for i in X:
    sigma += np.square(mean - i)

sigma = np.sqrt(sigma / (len(X) - 1))


def func(x):
    return np.exp(np.square(x - mean) / (2 * np.square(sigma))) / np.sqrt(2 * math.pi * sigma)


Y = []

for i in X:
    Y.append(func(i))

plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o', color='b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question properly, which I think that you are just trying to add more data points to generate a normal distribution curve.

```
mu = np.mean(X)
sigma = np.std(X) #You manually calculated it but you can also use this built-in function
data = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, SIZE_OF_DATA_YOU_NEED)
```

However, if you're also just trying to form the normal distribution curve, you can't just be plotting each value against its probability density function.

Try

```
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(data, 30, normed=True)
plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Might want to concatenate X against the new data points too.

Hope this help in some way, also attaching a link to numpy.random.normal() in case it helps in some kind of way (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).